# ng-selected option interpolation failing in IE10

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-10

I've got an select block that looks like this:

```
<select ng-model="customfield">
            <option value="" disabled>Map to field</option>
            <option ng-repeat="option in fields" ng-selected="option.id === customfield.id" value="{{option.id}}">{{ option.custom_name }}</option>
            <option disabled>---</option>
            <option value="-1">Create new custom field</option>
</select>
```

On IE the selected option initially fails to interpolate. It shows up as {{ option.custom_name }}. If I click into the select box and click out of it the option shows up correctly. Any ideas on how to work around this?

Comment: have you tried using ng-bind instead of interpolation?

Comment: I've tried ng-bind. That doesn't work either. It displays a blank option rather than the raw interpolation. Again, that's only until I click in and out of the select box, then the selected option displays.

Comment: Just force your users to run it in Chrome, IE sucks anyways ;). But seriously, could you maybe post with your controller code in a fiddle or plunk?